# How to copy data from void pointer in C++?

Tags: c++

I past all param's data struct as `void*` to my function :

```
void func(void* param, size_t size) {
    // here I need copy data from param
    void * copy_data = malloc(size);
    memcpy(copy_data, param, size);
    ...
}

// call it like this
func(&data, sizeof(data));
```

When the param is `struct` and there is object inside it like this:

```
struct data {
    CustomClass object;
};
```

The `memcpy` will not copy the real data in `object`.

Is there any way to copy real data from `void*`? If not, what's the best practices about it? I think there must be someone had asked such question, I just can not find it :-)

Comment: How are you calling `func` with `data` ?

Comment: Deep copy constructors are designed for this.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès But I can not get the data type from `void*`, there will be many type past in `func`.

Comment: Then such a generic function cannot take in account structures like this.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès You're right, I need change `void*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a template instead?

```
template<class T>
void func(T const& param) {
    // here I need copy data from param
    T copy_data = param;
    ...
}

// call it like this
func(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you must not use `void*` along with structures and classes. `struct`/`class` may not be **POD** (Plain Object Data - having only data, no virtual-functions, constructors, destructors, inheritance etc.). Better write custom code to copy classes, preferably within class itself. That's why we have copy constructors, assignment operators to override.

Later, when you know and learn more of language, you can write template based code.

Comment: Thanks! I think template is what I want. @Simple answered ealier, so I will accept his answer :-)